# How to push (smaller) array of pictures into an (larger) array?

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, iteration

Frameworks Used: Angular + Ionic

Case: I am fetching some data from an API, and I need to show them each in one IonCard, however the array does not contain any picture, so I have locally stored some pictures in my assets file and I have stored the directory of each picture and a name in an array.

So Logically what I need to do is to loop through both arrays and push one picture to every object of the fetched array, but there are some difficulties like following one:

- Size of the pictures array is smaller, meaning some of the IonCards will have no image.

So I just need some help on this function, hope I have clarified the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is the function that I have written to solve my problem, I thought this might help those who need to merge two arrays with different sizes. FYI, I have written this function in my component's .ts file.

```
loadedJobs = [];
.
.
.
fetchJobs(){
    this.ws.get<Jobs>('/aplink/jobs')
    .pipe(map(responseData => {
      Object.assign(this.loadedJobs, responseData.models);
        var i: number = 0;
        var n: number = 0;
        while (i < this.loadedJobs.length) {
            this.loadedJobs[i] = Object.assign(this.loadedJobs[i], {
              img: this.people[n].img
            });
            if ((this.people.length)-1 == n){
              n = 0;
            } else {
              n++;
            }
          i++;
          }
    })).subscribe();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is try to parse both arrays into the same type of object (ex. 'Picture'), and then use the concat method for arrays.

You can read about this method here
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

About the dimensions of photos I dont know if the change a lot but I would suggest modifying css to make imgs have static height and width.